# Precompile VueJS template only files

Tags: vue.js

I am writing a single page app with VueJS. I have a lot of html elements sharing the same style across differents files. To simplify my job and clear the template section I've created .vue files to encapsulate commom html block.

For example I have files like `AccentBox.vue`:

```
<template>
    <div class="bg-accent rounded-lg p-4 flex cursor-pointer">
        <div class="m-auto flex flex-row">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The problem is that it increase the bundle size a lot and in the browser side it has a big performance overhead.

Example of the `Home.vue`:

```
<Box class="mt-5">
    <GrowingAnimation>
        <Header1>Titre:</Header1>
        <Text class="mt-2">{{todo.title}}</Text>

        <ClickScale>
            <AccentBox class="mt-5 flex flex-row gap-4">
                <TrashIcon class="h-10" />
            </AccentBox>
        </ClickScale>
    </Animation>
</Box>
```

I want to know if there is a way to "precompile / transform" those component so that in the browser vuejs does not have to render the `AccentBox.vue` component and avoid having huge trees of nested vuejs components.

I already use the vuejs build command but browser side `AccentBox.vue` still is a component and take time to be processed by vue.

Transforming this:

```
<Header1>Titre:</Header1>
```

into

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold">Titre:</h1>
```

Is there any way to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your `AccentBox.vue` file represents a full-blown component, it does contain more overhead than simply writing out some divs. However, in Vue 3, this overhead is rather minimal, and there isn't a way to precompile something like a macro.

Vue allows us to write stateless components that simply render HTML, using something called a [render function](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#creating-vnodes). We can rewrite your `AccentBox` component like this:

```
import { h } from 'vue'

const AccentBox = (props, context) => {
  return h(
    'div',
    { class: 'bg-accent rounded-lg p-4 flex cursor-pointer' },
    h(
      'div',
      { class: 'm-auto flex flex-row' },
      context.slots
    )
  )
}

export default AccentBox
```

We can then import it in exactly the same way as a standard Vue file:

```
import AccentBox from 'AccentBox.js'
```